# How must be implemented "forall" to loop on every instance of a certain template

Tags: clips

My code:

```
(deftemplate person 

(slot name (type STRING))
(slot age (type STRING))
(multislot title (type STRING))
(slot areaofknowledge (type SYMBOL))
(slot yearTEDtalk (type STRING))

)

(deffacts init

(assert (person 
(name John)
(age 30)
(title Bla bla bla )
(areaofknowledge Bla)
(yearTEDtalk 2020)  
)   
)

(assert (person 
(name Laura)
(age 50)
(title Bla bla bla )
(areaofknowledge Bla)
(yearTEDtalk 2019)  
)   
)

) 

(defrules rules

 (defrule assignpersontotalk
 (forall (person
    (name ?nameTED) 
    (title ?titleTED)
    (year ?yearTED)
    )
    )

 =>
 (assert (TEDtalk-on ?titleTED ?yearTED ?nameTED ))
 )
 )
```

But seems this is not the rigth way to loop with foreall trough all persons, because im getting:
[image: Error]

Im not founding the solution on Google, and Clips manual only explains that you have to use foreall (patter1) (pattern2) which is not really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forall conditional element requires at least two patterns. It transforms patterns in this form:

```
(forall <pattern-1>
        <pattern-2>
            .
            .
            .
        <pattern-n>)
```

to this form:

```
(not (and <pattern-1>
          (not (and <pattern-2>
                        .
                        .
                        .
                    <pattern-n>))))
```

In any event, you don't have to explicitly iterate over facts matched by a rule:

```
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate person 
   (slot name)
   (slot age)
   (slot title)
   (slot areaofknowledge)
   (slot yearTEDtalk))
CLIPS> 
(deffacts init
   (person 
     (name John)
     (age 30)
     (title "Bla bla bla")
     (areaofknowledge Bla)
     (yearTEDtalk 2020))   
   (person 
     (name Laura)
     (age 50)
     (title "Bla bla bla")
     (areaofknowledge Bla)
     (yearTEDtalk 2019)))
CLIPS> 
(defrule assignpersontotalk
   (person
      (name ?nameTED) 
      (title ?titleTED)
      (yearTEDtalk ?yearTED))
    =>
    (assert (TEDtalk-on ?titleTED ?yearTED ?nameTED)))
CLIPS> (watch rules)
CLIPS> (watch facts)
CLIPS> (watch activations)
CLIPS> (reset)
<== f-0     (initial-fact)
==> f-0     (initial-fact)
==> f-1     (person (name John) (age 30) (title "Bla bla bla") (areaofknowledge Bla) (yearTEDtalk 2020))
==> Activation 0      assignpersontotalk: f-1
==> f-2     (person (name Laura) (age 50) (title "Bla bla bla") (areaofknowledge Bla) (yearTEDtalk 2019))
==> Activation 0      assignpersontotalk: f-2
CLIPS> (run)
FIRE    1 assignpersontotalk: f-2
==> f-3     (TEDtalk-on "Bla bla bla" 2019 Laura)
FIRE    2 assignpersontotalk: f-1
==> f-4     (TEDtalk-on "Bla bla bla" 2020 John)
CLIPS>
```

Comment: that worked perfectly. What about if i  wanted to not allow the same person to have 2 TEDTalks in the same year? Would you recommend any specific method/syntax to check if the new facts that "assignpersontotalk" rule creates, have the same person name field?

Comment: Add the pattern (not (Tedtalk-on ? ?yearTED ?nameTed)) to the conditions of the rule.

Comment: i'm curious about the meaning of that single ? you put after Tedtalk-on. I tried to remove it and the condition continues firing correctly. I hope you can explain me why is it necessary.

Comment: The ? means that there must be a value present but it does not matter what it is. Removing the ? allows the pattern to always match since there are no TEDtalk-on facts with just two fields. Unless you have at least two person facts with the same name and yearTEDTalk, the not TEDtalk-on pattern will have no effect.

Comment: perfectly explained!